# Unable to include django-summernote features

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to add django-summernote feature to my form but i am unable to do that.
here is my code
forms.py

```
class HomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    post = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Write a post here...',
            'post': SummernoteInplaceWidget(),
        }
    ))

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('post',)
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

template

## Status

{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.post }}
            
            Submit

### {{ text }}

{% for post in posts %}

## {{ post.post }}

Posted by {{ post.user.get_full_name }} on {{ post.created }}

{% endfor %}

and i included summernote url in urls.py

Comment: Does it produce any error message on console or elsewhere? Also, i don't quite get what are you doing with Summernote nested in `TextInput`… Does it work with a simple definition like `post = forms.CharField(widget=SummernoteInplaceWidget())`?

Comment: If i replace post=forms.CharField(widget=SummernoteInplaceWidget()), then it shows a error like this    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'widgets'